# Stimulate SQL like query tool in python/C++

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, rdbms, sql-parser

Implement SQL like query tool where from STDIN following things have to be read in the given order:-

```
1. Number of rows of the table (n) and Number of queries (q).
2. Table fields separated by Comma.
3. n line containing table rows of the table
4. q queries where clause.
```

We have to print output for each query on STDOUT.

Eg:-

**Input:**

`4,2`

```
"Name","Age","Sex","Salary"

1,"Joy",21,"M",2000

2,"Alan",28,"M",500

3,"John",30,"M",1000

4,"Nemo",45,"F",1500

Salary>=1000

Sex="M" and Salary>499
```

**Output:**

```
2

3
```

Can you guys tell how should I approach the problem?
And What data structure should I be using to store the table and process the queries ?

PS: I am not asking for the ready made solution, I just need step wise help in solving this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the excersise is impelenting SQL like for practice (and not real SQL becuase this is the obvious solution).

I'd have a list of dictionaries (a dict for each row) fill it with the data and than use list comprehension to filter the lines

```
[ line for line in lines if (line['Sex']=='M') and (line['Salary'] > 499)]
```

Of course you have a lot of parsing to do to create such a python command - but this is the direction

Comment: Yes, It is just for practise. How should I go about it ?

Comment: I edited the answer for an example of what you need to create. Basically filling the list is iterating line by line, and creating the queries is a lot of splitting and comparing (and you can do something fancy with regex if you want to challenge yourself)

Comment: Thanks. But How Do I store the rows in dictionary? and how will I know wether the input for particular column will be int or string or date?            Ps: I know I sound stupid, but I dint get much help from google.

Comment: On a real SQL you specify the type when you create the tables (in the scheme) - here is an excersize - you "know" the type (name is string, age is int, etc...)

Comment: you can try and "guess" but usually it is not robust (for instance try and convert it to a number) - but again - in this example - you are supposed to know the types